# passing boolean function to if-condition in python

Tags: python

I"m learning python, and I'm trying to do this, which I thought should be trivial, but apparently, it's not.

```
$python
>>> def isTrue(data):
...     "ping" in data
... 
>>> if isTrue("ping"):
...     print("pong")       >>>>>>>>>>>>>> shouldn't this print "pong"???
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to return the value. *Then*, it will work.

```
>>> def isTrue(data):
...     return "ping" in data
... 
>>> if isTrue("ping"):
...     print("pong")
...
pong
>>>
```

Comment: Oooh! That makes sense! Jeese, I can't believe being a java-pgrammaer for all these years, I could forget such a thing. I always thought Python was the "magic" language where you could almost write *anything*, and the interpreter would understand. :)

Comment: @OneTwoThree, python is awesome no doubt. But we _all_ have limits. :)

Comment: If you do not have an explicit return, python will return the value None -- so it is kindof magic still. :)