# Condition not passing into if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to increase the count each time the function is run, it seems as though count is being reset each time the function is run. I think the count in the if statement may not be the same one that's passed as a condition. Thanks

```
def check_solution(user_solution, solution, count):

if user_solution == solution:
        count =+1
        print(count)
        return count
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

this is the code I'm using to call the function

```
if index == 1:
    solution = num_1 + num_2
    num_1 = str(num_1)
    num_2 = str(num_2)
    problem = (num_1 + "+" + num_2)
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
    check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
    return count
```

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: can you [edit] your question to include how you're calling it and fix the indentation?

Comment: The `count` in the parameter list is the same `count` that's used in the body of your function. Is your calling code capturing the returned `count`? OTOH, the function returns `None` in the `else` clause, i.e., if `user_solution == solution` isn't true. That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing boolean function to if-condition in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588438/passing-boolean-function-to-if-condition-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check_solution` probably shouldn't be its own function, but let's address the issues:

- As yeniv mentioned: `count =+1` is `count = +1` or `count = 1`, which is clearly not your intent.
- `check_solution` only returns the count if you got the answer correct. Your `else` should also return the count (presumably unmodified).
- You don't do anything with the count that is returned:

  `check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)`

  should be:

  `count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)`

So to fix the issues from your current code:

```
def check_solution(user_solution, solution, count):
    if user_solution == solution:
        count =+1
        print(count)
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    return count
```

Please note, the `count` variable in the function and the `count` variable where you call it **are different**. You could change the name in the function and get the same result:

```
def check_solution(user_solution, solution, func_count):
    if user_solution == solution:
        func_count =+1
        print(func_count)
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    return func_count
```

and when calling it, you have to tell python where to put the result:

```
if index == 1:
    solution = num_1 + num_2
    num_1 = str(num_1)
    num_2 = str(num_2)
    problem = (num_1 + "+" + num_2)
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
    count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
    return count
```

If I was writing this myself, I would forego the function entirely and use a proper string formatter:

```
if index == 1:
    solution = num_1 + num_2
    problem = "%d+%d" % (num_1, num_2)  # or %f if you're using floats
    if solution == get_user_solution(problem):
        count += 1
        print(count)
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    return count
```

Comment: That's great, program works exactly as it should now

Answer (score 2):

The statement should be `count += 1` and not `count =+1`

Comment: either way it still does the same thing

Comment: If it is giving you same result, that's probably because the other pieces of your code also have some issues. The new piece of code that you have added in the update still does not give a complete picture so it's difficult to say. But that increment statement has to be corrected anyway. If you can add some more code to make it clear how `count` is being managed, maybe someone can help.